# redux useDispatch - constantly reloading page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I'm using `useDispatch` in `useEffect` it constantly Reloading the whole component

This is my Actions:

```js
export const getData = () => dispatch => {

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) =>
        json.map((obj) => ({
          ...obj,
          bonus: 1500,
          remaining: 230,
          active: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1 ? "yes" : "no",
        }))
      )
      .then((response) =>
        dispatch({ type: constants.REQUEST_PLAYERS_SUCCESS, payload: response })
      )
      .catch( error => dispatch({type: constants.REQUEST_PLAYERS_FAILED, payload: error}))
};
```

This is my Reducers:

```js
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: false,
};

export const changeGridData = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.REQUEST_PLAYERS_PENDING:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case constants.REQUEST_PLAYERS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, data: action.payload, isLoading: false};
    case constants.REQUEST_PLAYERS_FAILED:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getData } from "../store/gridPlayersLoad/gridPlayersActions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Bonuses = () => {
 const content = useSelector((state) => state); 
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getData())
 }, []);

 // Some other code...
}
```

What might be the reason why it keeps reloading?

Comment: The reason it keep reloading might be related the the parent component of `Bonuses`, and not the `Bonuses` component itself. Your dispatch must be affecting something else that is listening to the effects of the event.

Comment: The only parent component of the `Bonuses` is only one which holds react-router `<Route
                        path="/bonuses"
                        component={() => <Bonuses />}
                      />`

Comment: Just checked on another component with same reducer - works fine. So, yeah need to take a deeper look at `Bonuses` - Thanks!

Comment: Could you send us your full code for Bonuses so we have a better picture? I have a feeling something else must be interfering, because what you have shown us so far looks fine.

Comment: I removed everything except this part and still got this issue. But all components which are inside router-switch has this issue

Comment: And what about the components wrapping your router, are they affected by the redux state changes?

Comment: yes, and I think I found the reason why is it keep reloading - again thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm going to write an answer pointing to that just so that this question gets some clarity.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your implementation of `useEffect` and `useDispatch` based off what you've provided.

Whatever is causing your unintentional refreshes must be caused by a component higher up in your application that is being affected by the redux state changes.

When the wrapping component subscribed to the redux state experiences a state change, it will re-render. This could cause a change in which components are mounted/unmounted.

In your case, something is causing the Router to be remounted, which means that all the components in the routes with a `useEffect` hook will run those mounting effects again.